# How can I tell if the home I just bought has real wood countertops?

Tags: kitchen-counters

I am wanting to resurface my countertops but I do not want to ruin them.

How can I tell if they are real wood countertops?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKfdP.jpg]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you add a picture of the edge of the counter on the sides? That would be the most definite way of telling

Comment: Uploaded. I believe that answered my question

Comment: I think that instead of "real wood" your question would be improved if you said "solid wood"; there's a difference between "real", "fake" (the opposite of real), "veneer" and "solid". As opposed to asking if your countertops are "real or fake" you intended to ask if they are "veneer or solid".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you have wood veneer over particle board with wood edge banding and backer sheet.
You have to be careful if you are going to sand /refinish as you don't want to (you most likely will) go through the veneer. Veneer can be 1/16 to 1/8 of an inch thick.

Comment: Real wood veneers on plywood are on the order of thickness of 1/32" or less. The veneer on particle board backer is far more likely to be imitation wood and would be even thinner at 1/64".or less. Imitation wood may be a vinyl sheet bonded to the surface or a paper like material with with some type of plastic coating.

Comment: For cabinets and furniture, yes veneer would be very very thin. For counter tops we always went with thicker veneer up to 3/32 of an inch. (not laminate)

Comment: Wood veneer, in this case,  is "real" wood.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 remove a drawer, go into the cabinet and drill or sand the under side of the counter to see if it's solid.

Method 2 do a test run somewhere inconspicuous like behind the toaster.  If it's veneer you can patch it with an iron on patch and it won't matter too much.